# Pattern-rewriting Pattern triggers error?

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to rewrite patterns. For example, I'd like to rewrite the pattern

```
jFoo_Integer
```

which has `FullForm`

```
Pattern[jFoo,Blank[Integer]]
```

into just

```
Blank[Integer]
```

In other words, I want to strip out the names of patterns. I tried the following

```
jFoo_Integer /. {Pattern[nym_, Blank[typ_]] :> {nym, typ}}
```

which does not match or reduce and produces the (IMO bogus) error message

```
Pattern::patvar: First element in pattern Pattern[nym_,Blank[typ_]] is not a valid pattern name. >>
```

I also tried

```
    Pattern[jFoo,Blank[Integer]] /. {Pattern[nym_, Blank[typ_]] :> {nym, typ}}
    Pattern[jFoo,Blank[Integer]] /. {Verbatim[Pattern][nym_, Blank[typ_]] :> {nym, typ}}
    jFoo_Integer /. {Verbatim[Pattern][nym_, Blank[typ_]] :> {nym, typ}}
    jFoo_Integer /. {Verbatim[Pattern][nym_, Blank[typ_]] :> {nym, typ}}
```

all with exactly the same (failed) results.

Any hints, please & thanks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is probably

```
jFoo_Integer /. Verbatim[Pattern][nym_, Verbatim[Blank][typ_]] :> {nym, typ}
(* {jFoo, Integer} *)
```

The usage of [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Verbatim.html) points it out

> `Verbatim[expr]` represents `expr` in pattern matching, requiring that `expr` be matched exactly as it appears, **with no substitutions for blanks** or other transformations.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how do you want to work with it, but those are ways to go:

```
List @@ (jFoo_Integer)
```

> ```
> {jFoo, _Integer}
> ```

```
(jFoo_Integer) /. x_Pattern :> {x[[1]], x[[2]]}
```

> ```
> {jFoo, _Integer}
> ```

```
(jFoo_Integer)[[2]]
```

> ```
> _Integer
> ```