# "Meta-matching" patterns

Tags: pattern-matching

The title refers to the general problem of writing patterns to match pattern-containing expressions (hence "meta-match").

Here's an example.

In the following rules

```
0 -> "A"
foo[1] -> bar[2]
{1, 10} -> 11
```

the left-hand-sides contain no patterns, at least explicitly.  I'll refer to such rules as being "pattern-free".

Now, given a list of rules (`rules`), how can one obtain the sublist consisting only of the pattern-free ones?

This naive solution won't work:

```
Cases[rules,x_ /; FreeQ[x, (Blank[___] | BlankSequence[___] | BlankNullSequence[___])]]
```

I can solve this problem at least with the following hack

```
Cases[(rules /. (Blank | BlankSequence | BlankNullSequence) -> $patt),
      y_ /; FreeQ[y, $patt[___]]]
```

or

```
Cases[(rules /. x:(Blank | BlankSequence | BlankNullSequence) -> $patt[x]),
      y_ /; FreeQ[y, $patt[_][___]]
] /. $patt[z_] -> z
```

...but I figure that *Mathematica* may provide standard constructs to deal with such situations.  If so, I'd like to learn what they are.

Comment: `Verbatim` and `PatternHold` are useful.

Comment: What @Szabolcs said. Except the second one should be `HoldPattern`.

Comment: Related: [(2778)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2778/121),
[(17591)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17591/121),
[(17892)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17892/121),  [(38436)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38436/121),
[(43972)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43972/121)

Comment: How would you owant to deal with expressions with things like `x[Verbatim[2/;True]]` or `x[HoldPattern[2]]`?